# Предупреждение об использовании типа auto Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

```
warning: 'auto' type specifier is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
```

Выскакивает это предупреждение, когда использую тип "auto", хотя ввел верный стандарт C++. Среда Visual Studio Code. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как от этого избавиться?

[image: C_Cpp > Default Cpp Standard:[c++11]]

Comment: Стандарт необходимо указывать при компиляции.

Comment: Предупреждение вам выдает компилятор, VSC тут вообще не при чем.